# Why `make` fail during Virtuoso 7.1?

Tags: makefile, virtuoso

I'm trying to install [virtuoso 7.1](https://codeload.github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/zip/v7.1.0), and as said in `README` and `INSTALL` files I ran `autogen.sh`, `./configure`, it works.
But the command `make` doesn't work, I don't know why. There was an error with `ranlib` saying `randlib` was called without arguments.

Comment: The makefile seems to be running `ranlib` without any arguments. You can try to look at the makefile to see where/why that is happening.

Comment: I just verify, in the Makefile there is only one line where there is `ranlib` :
RANLIB = ranlib

Comment: That's a variable assignment. Now you need to find what uses `$(RANLIB)` or `${RANLIB}`.

Comment: I verified all Makefile, there are only assignment variables for RANLIB.
RANLIB is used only on configure file.

Comment: Can you find that `ar cru ....` command line in your makefiles anywhere? Or that `../../libtool` command? If you run `make -d` then you'll get very verbose output which will tell you where in the make process this error is happening.

Comment: No I can't find `ar cru ...` in my Makefiles.
I can't find `../../libtool`, but `libtool` is written 1300 times in each Makefile

Answer (score 1):

If the `makefile` uses a variable for the ranlib executable (e.g. with `RANLIB = ranlib`, then you might get further with

```
make RANLIB=:
```

or, if that doesn't work,

```
make RANLIB=echo
```

effectively making the ranlib invocation a no-op. These days, ranlib is usually no longer needed.

Comment: RANLIB is already defined, in the Makefile there is a line `RANLIB = ranlib`
Your commands doesn't works :/

Comment: @AnthonyB What about these doesn't work? They should run `:` or `echo` instead of `ranlib` at the place where it fails and that should get the build farther at least.

Comment: If the build process is running `ranlib` then it would seem likely to expect that the build needs it, no?

Comment: @EtanReisner If I define RANLIB at the same time than `make`, there is no difference. RANLIB is defined in all Makefile.
But if I define RANLIB before configure, the error during `make` is different :

    ** ERROR **: Code generation failed while running the following command:

    /usr/local/bin/gperf -aCDGptr -Kkwd -L ANSI-C -k1,2,3,5,7,$ --ignore-case -Nsparql_lex_hash_kw sparqlwords.gperf

Comment: If you run the *exact* commands given in this post without having done anything else you still get the `ranlib` error/usage output like in the post? (Without having changed `RANLIB` before `configure` or anything?) And yes, I don't think disabling `ranlib` is the solution here.

Comment: I corrected the error written in my previous comment.
Now I run the command make `RANLIB=echo`, and the error is different, there is no ranlib in the error. I post the new error in the question